# Will stress testing a QA instance on the same SQL Server as the Live Intance affect performance of that Live instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am doing some stress testing on a QA instance which is installed on the same SQL Server instance on Azure, as the Live instance. I have been changing it between, via "scale", between "Web", "S1" and "S2".  It has occurred to me that I might be negatively affecting the live DB instance's performance. Am I correct? Perhaps what I should do is create a QA SQL Server instance and then test on this seperate to Live?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are separate databases, even if they are on the same logical server, they are still on separate nodes with dedicated computing power (unless you are using Web/Business, which is shared). This is true for all the current tiers (Basic, Standard, Premium).

If you are using Elastic Pools than you would have sharing of DTU usage between your databases but you can specify how much each database can use.

Comment: Do I assume that if I have a QA "Web" instance and a Live "Web" instance on the same logical server, then stress testing the QA "Web" instance could impact my Live "Web" Instance, or is it more general than that, in that I could impact any other user using "Web" SQL instances?

Comment: More general, so in theory they should never be on the same physical nodes but your usage will affect other databases on that same node and visa versa.

Comment: @SamJolly, I highly encourage you to do your testing against Basic, Standard, and Premium edition databases as Web and Business editions will be retired this fall.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek, Thanks for this. Yes I realise this. Just trying to understand the differences in operation which cbattlegear has clarified.

Answer (score 1):

It could impact if it is a WEB / BUSINESS database. Also web / business are depricated and will be retired soon. However it shouldn't be the case with BASIC / STANDARD / PREMIUM tiers. I would recommend upgrading server to V12 and perform the tests so that you get the latest code running and need not repeat them once you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes will be moving off "Web", but not to V12, as I have found my queries take longer than on V11. I have tried all Compatibility levels ie 100, 110 and 120. Admittedly the DB was originally developed on SQL 2008 and is Comp Level 100.

Comment: are you comparing the query performance on the same tiers on v11 and v12?

Comment: Yes I have compared the same tiers, and suprised to find, on my SQL 2008 developed DB, that it runs slower on V12. S2/V11 10 users is equivalent to S2/V12 5 users ie around 660 ms average http response for my test case. S2/V11 - 20 users is 1180ms and S2/V12 20 users is 4190ms. Just done a "Web" test on 20 users = 782ms !!! OK I accept "Web" can be variable, but this is an incredible result. The users are ramped up over 300 secs by the way. P1/20 user is 700ms, S3/20 users is 1000ms.